# how to move to the next enclosing brackets in VI

Tags: c++, vim, vi

Are there any shortcuts to move to the next enclosing brackets. For ex:

```
int func()
{

 if(true)
 {//this point

   for(int i=0;i<10;i++)
   {//need to jump from here to

    //blah blah blah

   }

 }
}
```

I can move to the beginning of a function using `[[` but not sure how to move to the next enclosing brackets. Thanks for any info...

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Can't think of anything easier than `/{`

`[{` will go to an unmatched one, but that isn't what you want.

Comment: This will get me to the next { which is not what I want. May be ?{ will work. Please see the comments in the code snippet

Answer (score 21):

Put the cursor on one bracket and hit the percent key.

Also setting the 'showmatch' option makes the cursor jump to the matching opening bracket when you type the closing bracket.

Adding a declaration like this:

```
set matchpairs+=<:>
```

Will add angle brackets to the standard list of match pair brackets.

Answer (score 10):

For the next enclosing brace do ]}, but in your example you are looking for the previous. In that case try [{.

Comment: This should be the accepted answer. Read the vim help for [{:
*[...] can be used to go to the start or end of the current
code block.  It is like doing "%" on the '(', ')', '{' or '}' at the other
end of the code block, but you can do this from anywhere in the code block.
Very useful for C programs.  Example: When standing on "case x:", "[{" will
bring you back to the switch statement.*

Comment: how do i go to enclosing ']'

Answer (score 2):

You place your cursor on the opening or closing bracket of which you want to find the matching bracket and then use %. This will lead you to the matching braces.

Answer (score 2):

You can use the keys `[` and `]` to cycle to the previous and next matching brackets respectively. Below are the common keybindings:

- `[(` - Previous `(`
- `[{` - Previous `{`
- `[<` - Previous `<`

and more interesting ones

- `[m` - Previous method start
- `[M` - Previous method end

> The same also applies for next items:

- `]}` - Next `}`
- `])` - Next `)`
- `]>` - Next `>`

The reason why this method is more effective is that you can specify count together with the commands for example:

With combo `3[{`, I can jump from line 8 to line 2 `{`

```
1 int func()
2 { // @end
3
4 if(true)
5 {
6
7   for(int i=0;i<10;i++)
8   { // @start
9
10    //blah blah blah
11
12   }
13
14 }
15 }
```

To read more on square bracket motions enter `:help [` in vim command line

Answer (score 0):

There's always /{

That is, search for the next open brace.

Answer (score 0):

Hover on '{' and press * (jump to char next occurrence) or # (jump to char previous occurrence).